# Wrong selectedRow returned with touch device

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to work with the selected row of a Table when the device is a touch one in the `pointerPressed` method , and what I get is a wrong value : for example I clicked the third line ( PS : the header line is -1 ) and I got 0 as a value in the `System.out.println` ! And when I click another row then I get the row I selected before !
So how to synchronize LWUIT with the selected row ?

Comment: I loop the table components , for (short idxComp=3; idxComp < tList.getComponentCount(); idxComp++) , and I add them focusListener, in the focusGained method I get the selectedRow, and I also execute an action which shows a detail Form of the selected row. Now my problem is when the table Form is shown (first time or back ) then the focus is programatically placed at a certain cell of the table : tList.getComponentAt(c).requestFocus(); and the action of displaying the detail Form I need to be executed is not executed when I click on this cell ! So how to execute the action in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , I found the solution : in the constructor I wrote :

```
for (short idxComp=3; idxComp<tList.getComponentCount(); idxComp++)
        {
            tList.getComponentAt(idxComp).addFocusListener(this);
        }
isTableSelected = false;
```

And here are the implemented methods :

```
public void pointerPressed(int x, int y)
    {
        int startX, startY, endX, endY, nbComps;
        nbComps = tList.getComponentCount();
        startX = tList.getComponentAt(3).getAbsoluteX();
        endX = tList.getComponentAt(5).getAbsoluteX() + tList.getComponentAt(5).getWidth();
        startY = tList.getComponentAt(3).getAbsoluteY();
        endY = tList.getComponentAt(nbComps-1).getAbsoluteY() + tList.getComponentAt(nbComps-1).getHeight();
        if ( (x >= startX && x <= endX) && (y >= startY && y <= endY) )
        {
            isTableSelected = true;
            if ( (x >= selectedComp.getAbsoluteX() && x <= (selectedComp.getAbsoluteX()+selectedComp.getWidth())) && (y >= selectedComp.getAbsoluteY() && y <= (selectedComp.getAbsoluteY()+selectedComp.getHeight())) )
                afficheFicheCredit(selectedRow);
        }
    }
    public void focusGained(Component comp) {
        tList.repaint();
        selectedComp = tList.getComponentAt(3*selectedRow+3);
        if (isTableSelected)
        {
            isTableSelected = false;
            selectedRow = tList.getSelectedRow();
            afficheFicheCredit(selectedRow);
        }
    }
```